# Trouble targeting elements on website (selenium webdriver)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to target properties on a real estate website. Ideally, I want to pull the property marketing URL, the title, location, and email of each listing.  The properties are all listed as so:

```
<div class="propertyList">
        <div id="propertyList74495-sale" class="deal_on_market propertyListItem" data-property-id="74495-sale" data-listing-url="http://svncommercialadvisors.com/properties/?propertyId=74495-sale" data-listing-id="148815"></div>

           <table>
             <tbody>
                 <tr>
                   <td class="thumbnail">
                <a target="_top" href="http://svncommercialadvisors.com/properties/?propertyId=74495-sale"></a>
            </td>
            <td class="addressInfo">
                <a target="_top" href="http://svncommercialadvisors.com/properties/?propertyId=74495-sale">

                    Engelberg Antik's

                </a>
                <p class="propertiesListCityStateZip">
                    <img src="/images/map-marker-tiny.png?1427481879" alt="Map-marker-tiny"></img>


                    Salem, OR

                </p>
                <p class="description">

                    Outstanding downtown Salem opportunity, right next…

                </p>
                <div class="smallAttributes">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="propertyInfo">
                <div>

                    $479,900

                </div>
                <div>

                    13,612 SF

                </div>
                <div>

                    Street Retail

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="contactAdvisor">
    ::before
    <a href="mailto:brokeremail@svn.com"></a>


    or call
    503.588.0400
    for more information

</div>
<div class="links"></div>
```

```
        <div id="propertyList61436-sale" class="deal_under_contract propertyListItem" data-property-id="61436-sale" data-listing-url="http://svncommercialadvisors.com/properties/?propertyId=61436-sale" data-listing-id="124490"></div>

        <div id="propertyList89374-sale" class="deal_on_market propertyListItem" data-property-id="89374-sale" data-listing-url="http://svncommercialadvisors.com/properties/?propertyId=89374-sale" data-listing-id="173124"></div>

        <div id="propertyList84437-sale" class="deal_on_market propertyListItem" data-property-id="84437-sale" data-listing-url="http://svncommercialadvisors.com/properties/?propertyId=84437-sale" data-listing-id="164488"></div>

        <div id="propertyList84478-sale" class="deal_on_market propertyListItem" data-property-id="84478-sale" data-listing-url="http://svncommercialadvisors.com/properties/?propertyId=84478-sale" data-listing-id="164538"></div>

         ...
```

this was my first attempt at it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
import smtplib
import pymongo

newProperties = []

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://svncommercialadvisors.com/properties/')

for property in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('propertyList'):
    #get title,location 
    info = property.find_elements_by_class_name('addressInfo')
    email = property.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('.com')
```

When I run the above, it doesn't give any errors that the driver can't locate elements.  However, when I print out the elements nothing appears. How can I better locate the elements? I would like for something like this, appended to a list:

```
-title: Engelberg Antik's
-location: Salem, OR
-url: http://svncommercialadvisors.com/properties/?propertyId=74495-sale
-email: brokeremail@svn.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key problem here is that the *search results are loaded in an `iframe`*.

You need to **switch to `iframe`** before searching for properties.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://svncommercialadvisors.com/properties/')

# wait for frame to appear and switch
frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#buildout iframe")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

for property in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('propertyList'):
    info = property.find_element_by_class_name('addressInfo')
    email = property.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Email')

    print info.text
    print print email.get_attribute('href')
```

I've also applied two fixes:

- replaced `find_elements_by_class_namme` with `find_elements_by_class_name`
- replaced `property.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('.com')` with `property.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Email')`

It prints:

```
Engelberg Antik's
Salem, OR
Outstanding downtown Salem opportunity, right next door to the newly renovated Roth and McGilchri...
mailto:jennifer.martin@svn.com
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I make it print that for all the properties on the page? I guessed it would print that for each property in the for

Comment: @RobertOttolia sure, just one more change: `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('propertyListItem')` instead of `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('propertyList')`.